# `tf.keras.layers.Flatten()` not working for some odd reason

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape, flatten

I have the following sample code in Python:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a tensor of shape (14, 2)
x = tf.constant([[1, 2], 
                 [3, 4], 
                 [5, 6], 
                 [7, 8], 
                 [9, 10],
                 [11, 12],
                 [13, 14], 
                 [15, 16], 
                 [17, 18], 
                 [19, 20], 
                 [21, 22], 
                 [23, 24], 
                 [25, 26], 
                 [27, 28]])

# Flatten the tensor
y = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

print(x)
print(y)
```

Now the output that I expect from this code is the following:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  2]
 [ 3  4]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 7  8]
 [ 9 10]
 [11 12]
 [13 14]
 [15 16]
 [17 18]
 [19 20]
 [21 22]
 [23 24]
 [25 26]
 [27 28]], shape=(14, 2), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28], shape=(28,), dtype=int32)
```

But instead of this, I'm getting the following output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  2]
 [ 3  4]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 7  8]
 [ 9 10]
 [11 12]
 [13 14]
 [15 16]
 [17 18]
 [19 20]
 [21 22]
 [23 24]
 [25 26]
 [27 28]], shape=(14, 2), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  2]
 [ 3  4]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 7  8]
 [ 9 10]
 [11 12]
 [13 14]
 [15 16]
 [17 18]
 [19 20]
 [21 22]
 [23 24]
 [25 26]
 [27 28]], shape=(14, 2), dtype=int32)
```

This suggests that the Flatten layer had absolutely no impact of the initial tensor `x`.

Please help me understand why that is. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is intended behavior, the first axis is assumed to be the batch axis which is not supposed to be flattened in a neural network context. Flatten is to be used to turn e.g. a shape of (14, 3, 3, 2) into (14, 18).

Answer (score 0):

The comment that `@xdurch0` posted implies that the solution is to simply add another square brackets `[]` around the initial constant tensor, Like so:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a tensor of shape (1, 14, 2)
x = tf.constant([[[1, 2], 
                 [3, 4], 
                 [5, 6], 
                 [7, 8], 
                 [9, 10],
                 [11, 12],
                 [13, 14], 
                 [15, 16], 
                 [17, 18], 
                 [19, 20], 
                 [21, 22], 
                 [23, 24], 
                 [25, 26], 
                 [27, 28]]])

# Flatten the tensor
y = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

print(x)
print(y)
```

So now the input shape would be `(1, 14, 2)`. This worked. Thank you for the comment. I'm posting the answer so that this could help others stuck in the same problem.